# How to insert check box values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose

I have a check box in which when i check yes i should push an array in such a way that it should look like below

```
"students" : [ 
            {
                "student" : ObjectId("58510c7694655961ea01d752"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("58512c6577464c1926a68ebf"),
                "ispresent" : ""
            }
           ]
```

my template,

```
 <div class="btn-group col-sm-6" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-white">
                      <input type="radio" name="" value="" ng-click="checkvalues('Yes',student.id)" autocomplete="off"> Yes
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-white">
                      <input type="radio" name=""  value="" autocomplete="off"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
```

I am not sure whether ngclick works,can any one help me please.

Comment: And where is your checkbox? I only see radio buttons

Comment: Where is the code for checkvalues()?  Sharing more of your controller code would be helpful.